# "warning: already initialized constant" in spec_helper.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, spork

We have a rather large test suite that no one has used in a while, and while trying to get back to testing I keep encountering this when running `bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/test_spec.rb`:

```
spec/spec_helper.rb:82: warning: already initialized constant THIS_ID
spec/spec_helper.rb:83: warning: already initialized constant THAT_ID
spec/spec_helper.rb:84: warning: already initialized constant RANDOM_ID
```

And no tests are completed. This same error appears on every rspec test file I try. However, when I disable Spork, everything runs fine (all the tests fail, but they haven't been touched in a long time).

Part of my `spec_helper.rb` is

```
Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.
  FactoryGirl.reload
  Department.where(name: ['This', 'That', 'Random']).destroy_all
  FactoryGirl.create(:department, name: 'This')
  FactoryGirl.create(:department, name: 'That')
  FactoryGirl.create(:department, name: 'Random')
  THIS_ID = Department.where(name: 'This').first.id
  THAT_ID = Department.where(name: 'That').first.id
  RANDOM_ID = Department.where(name: 'Random').first.id
end
```

We use Spork, FactoryGirl among other things.

Obviously I obfuscated the variable names.

Comment: It’s just a warning, it’s not that that’s preventing your tests from running.

Comment: I personally prefer to stub constant instead of overriding it.

Comment: Constants does not exists in Ruby, they can be set, unset and set again at anytime. This is why you get warnings, because the Constant `THIS_ID` has already been set (or initialized) and you set it again. It is "violating" the concept of the constant. But heh, no other way to do it with Ruby! (http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_constants.html)

Comment: @BuckDoyle, it is preventing the tests from running. It displays those warnings then stops.

Comment: What I’m saying is that I think if you removed the constant definitions, it would still not run the tests. It’s a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using global variables instead of constants. Even better, try to put initializers inside `before`

```
describe Something do
  before do
    @this_id = Department.where(name: 'This').first.id
    @that_id = Department.where(name: 'That').first.id
    @random_id = Department.where(name: 'Random').first.id
  end
end
```